# Stenography system for the Latin language

Tags: paleography

I am aware of [Tironian notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes) but it has several thousand signs, so I was wondering if during the history of the Latin language a smaller/simpler system was developed to be able to write more quickly in Latin.